# Find a bijection between $H\times K$ and $HK\times H\cap K$, where $H, K$ are subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H, K\le G$. It is a known fact that, if $H, K$ are finite, then $\begin{aligned}|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}\end{aligned}$, where $HK:=\{hk:h\in H, k\in K\}$. I'm trying to prove this fact by finding a bijection between $H\times K$ and $HK\times H\cap K$, but nothing intuitive comes to my mind. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious (set theoretic map) between $H\times K$ and $HK$ sends the pair $(h,k)$ to the element $hk$.

When do two pairs give you the same product?

If $(h,k)$ and $(h',k')$ map to the same element, then $hk=h'k'$, so $(h')^{-1}h = k'k^{-1}\in H\cap K$. So pairs mapping to the same element give you an element in the intersection.

If $u\in H\cap K$, then $(h,k)$ and $(hu,u^{-1}k)$ give you the same product. So elements in the intersection give you the same product.

So to actually define a bijection from $HK\times (H\cap K)$ to $H\times K$, consider selecting first a specific way of writing each element of $HK$, and go from there.